# synchronized LinkedList - peek

Tags: java, linked-list, thread-safety, peek

A `LinkedList` has **convenient `peek`, `pop`, ... methods.**

Unfortunately, I need **a thread-safe `LinkedList`**. So, my first idea was to wrap it as follows:

```
List<Object> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());
```

However, since the `List` interface does not contain the `peek` or `pop` methods. This doesn't work of course.

Alternatively, I could use `synchronized(list)` blocks all over the code. Is that the way to go ?

Any solutions that I'm overlooking ?

---

**EDIT:**

There are many reasons why one would use a `LinkedList`. I see some people are proposing other collections. So, here follow the brief requirements, which lead to my decision of using a `LinkedList`.

More background information:

- I'm using a LinkedList because the items need to be ordered.
- Items should be added in a non-blocking way.
- Items are added in the back ; removed from the front.
- Before the first item is removed, it first needs to be `peek`ed and validated. If validation fails, then the item needs to stay in the list.
- Only if the validation completed successfully, then the first item is removed.
- The queue needs to have a maximum size (to avoid memory issues).

Comment: An implementation of `BlockingQueue` would be a better choice. It's designed for concurrent access, and supports `peek` and `take` (which is basically `pop`).

Comment: You may want to look at `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`.

Comment: Maybe add a wrapper class around your list that has these peek/pop methods - and passes it on to the sync list?

Comment: Or [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html)

Comment: As others have noted, BlockingQueue is more appropriate, but if you must use a LinkedList (can't see why), then you have the List methods get(0) and remove(0) as equivalent to peek and pop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need `peek` to work, making a synchronized wrapper may not be sufficient, so you would have to write `synchronized` explicitly.

It is not so much a problem with writing a wrapper as it is a problem with the semantic of the `peek` method. Unlike the `pop` method, which represents a single action, `peek` method is often used in a multi-component action composed of `peek`-ing and then doing something else based on what `peek` returns.

If you synchronize in a wrapper, the result would be the same as if you wrote this code manually:

```
String s;
synchronized(list) {
    s = list.peek();
}
// <<== Problem ==>>
if (s != null) {
    synchronized(list) {
        s = list.pop();
    }
}
```

This presents a problem, because there is a moment in time when your list can change in between of `peek` and `pop` (this place in code above is marked as "Problem").

A proper way to do check-and-modify is doing it in a single `synchronized` block, i.e.

```
synchronized(list) {
    String s = list.peek();
    if (s != null) {
        s = list.pop();
    }
}
```

However, this cannot be done in a simple wrapper, because two list operations are performed in a single `synchronized` block.

You can avoid writing `synchronized` in multiple places by building your own data structure that encapsulates a `LinkedList<T>`, and provides operations that perform all test-and-modify operations in a synchronized block. This is not a simple problem, however, so you may be better off changing your algorithm in a way that it could work with one of pre-defined concurrent containers.

Comment: Yes, the key is that no builtin concurrent stack-like collection supports atomicity between "peek" and "pop" operations. You need a new method that takes a `Predicate` as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a concurrent `Queue`. `LinkedList` implements `List`, `Deque`, and `Queue`.  The `Queue` is what gives it the FIFO (adding in back, remove from front) semantics with peek and pop.

A [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) can be bounded, which is one of your criteria.  There are several other concurrent Queues and Deques to choose from as well.

Comment: Isn't it the case that a `LinkedBlockingQueue` blocks the moment you add an item, until an item is removed on the other end ? --> that's something I try to avoid. The add should be asynchronous (i.e. non-blocking).

Comment: You've got it backwards. `Take` will block, but `add` is non blocking.